# counting the number of elements of a list using recursive function without using len

Tags: python

I saw this code:

```
def list_length(my_lis):
    if mylist:
        return 1 + list_length(my_lis[1:])
    return 0
```

This code counts the number of elements in the list recursively without using len function.
Can someone please explain the list_length(my_lis[1:]) and how it gets added to 1 because from my understanding, my_lis[1:] gives the list without the first element. So how can this give the number of elements in a list?

Comment: "my_lis[1:] gives the list without the first element." Okay, so then `list_length(my_lis[1:])` should give the length of that list, right? Now, compared to the original list, how long is that? If you add 1 to that result, what do you get? What exactly is the conceptual difficulty here?

Answer (score 3):

Ahh recursion, tends to make things more complex than they need to be, but it's still cool!

Let's add some debug code to see what is happening

```
def list_length(my_lis):
    if my_lis:
        print(my_lis)
        length = list_length(my_lis[1:])
        print(str(my_lis) + " returning 1 + " + str(length))
        return 1 + length 
    print("Empty List! Return 0")
    return 0

test_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

answer = list_length(test_list)

print("Answer: " + str(answer))
```

This will output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['2', '3', '4']
['3', '4']
['4']
Empty List! Return 0
['4'] returning 1 + 0
['3', '4'] returning 1 + 1
['2', '3', '4'] returning 1 + 2
['1', '2', '3', '4'] returning 1 + 3
Answer: 4
```

Notice how we only reach the base case (return 0) after the list is empty. Also notice that the number doesn't start going up until AFTER we hit the base case. Only after we reach an empty list can we start going back up the chain and counting 1 + whatever the last function got.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
my_lis = [1,2,3]
```

if condition satisfies because list isn't empty so returns 1+list_length(my_lis[1:]) meaning my_lis[1:] means [2,3] . So to generalize it you are decreasing length of list by one, that is you count the first element and ignore the first element.

```
return 1+ list_length(my_lis[1:])            #my_lis=[2,3]
return 1+ 1+ list_length(my_lis[1:])         #my_lis=[3]
return 1+ 1+ 1+ list_length(my_lis[1:])      #my_lis=[]
return 1+ 1+ 1+ 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This goes as follows:

- If `my_lis` is not falsy (assumes non-empty list)
- Return 1 + call the same func on a list of the next item until the last
- If this new list is not falsy
- Return 1 + call the same func on a list of the next item until the last
- ...

This goes on until `my_lis[1:]` returns None, in this case instead of returning 1 we will return 0 and we do not trigger another recursive call.

Going from the innermost instead:

- `my_lis` is empty, `return 0`
- `my_lis` is not empty, `return 1 + 0`
- `my_lis` is not empty, `return 1 + (1 + 0)`
- `my_lis` is not empty, `return 1 + (1 + 1 + 0)`
- ...

This is how you end up with a list length.